Using CacheResultInterceptor causing deployment error
I hope, someone could help me with this.
Trying setup simplest project possible to get @CacheResult annotation in Jakarta EE (Wildfly-34.0.0.Final) work (with Cache-API RI).
Once I include CacheResultInterceptor in beans.xml
<interceptors>
    <class>org.jsr107.ri.annotations.cdi.CacheResultInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>

I get the following Deployment Error:
10:44:39,503 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-000900: 5.1.3 (Final)
10:44:39,946 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."sampleproject.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."sampleproject.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1609)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1438)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001417: Enabled interceptor class org.jsr107.ri.annotations.cdi.CacheResultInterceptor (<{https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee}class>org.jsr107.ri.annotations.cdi.CacheResultInterceptor</{https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee}class> in vfs:/C:/Users/dalib/IdeaProjects/sampleproject/content/sampleproject.war/WEB-INF/beans.xml@9) does not match an interceptor bean: the class is not found, or not annotated with @Interceptor and still not registered through a portable extension, or not annotated with @Dependent inside an implicit bean archive
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateEnabledInterceptorClasses(Validator.java:682)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:495)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:497)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:94)
    at org.jboss.as.weld@34.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:81)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1617)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1580)
    ... 6 more

Any idea es of why am I getting this error? This simple project is available on GitHub (one just need to download Wildfly-34.0.0.Final, point env-variable JBOSS_HOME to it and run mvn clean verify):
https://github.com/dkalna/sampleproject.git
Thank you and best regards
Dalibor

While WildFly 34 is a compatible implementation of the EE 10 Platform as well as the Web Profile and the Core Profile and thus using jakarta.* namespace, the JSR107 has never been updated since 2017 and thus cannot possibly be fully compatible with Jakarta EE. That's also one of the reasons why JSR107 is not bundled with the WildFly distributions while other Infinispan modules are available.

Hi Rado, thank you for your response. So what are my options here? To use infinispan-jcache library?
With Insinispan I hace tried following:

unzip wildfly-34.0.0.Final
copy infinispan-wildfly-modules-14.0.30.Final into wildfly/modules (btw, where do I find this module for infinispan 15?)
very same application as mentioned above produced very similar error, only for InjectedCacheResultInterceptor mentioned in beans.xml

What am I doing wrong?

The best way to move forward is to not rely on JSR107 JCache as that has been abandoned for many years with no signs of revival. If you need to, you would need to downgrade to  WildFly 26 which was the last Java EE 8 compatible distribution and use the appropriate Infinispan modules from infinispan.org website.

Ok, understood. Anyway, all that mentioned in https://infinispan.org/docs/14.0.x/titles/embedding/embedding.html#cdi_support is valid, right (CDI, Query, Counters and Locks)? And all that without the need of infinispan-wildfly-module, because it's already there?

Generally yes, clearly with the exception of JCache section. I suspect the documentation has not been updated in Infinispan after including them directly in WildFly distribution without needing a separate feature pack. For reference usage ideally refer to examples in https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/tree/34.0.0.Final/testsuite/integration/clustering/src/test/java/org/jboss/as/test/clustering/single/infinispan and https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/tree/34.0.0.Final/testsuite/integration/clustering/src/test/java/org/jboss/as/test/clustering/cluster/infinispan

Great! Now CDI works for me. Last question: Is it possible to inject Cache defined in standalone.xml? Something like this:







Following does not work:
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/cache/simpleContainer/simpleCache")
private Cache<String, String> simpleCache;

Getting error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYEE0117: Field simpleCache cannot be set - object of class org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.cache.LazyCache loaded by ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan" version 34.0.0.Final from local module loader (finder: local module finder (roots: c:\java\wildfly-34.0.0.Final\modules,c:\java\wildfly-34.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base)) is not assignable to interface org.infinispan.Cache loaded by ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.sampleproject.war" from Service Module Loader

Hi @Rado, could you please explain me that with caches defined in standalone.xml? Is it supposed to work? I have checked wildfly testsuite, but do not see through as of where are the caches defined. Thank you very much.

Hi there, it works now! Working project is here, free to checkout:
https://github.com/dkalna/sampleproject
Hopefuly can someone from infinity or wildfly project have a look and comment, whether this is the way it's supposed to be done?

You should definitely not be using LazyCache or similar internal classes, the correct way to inject the cache is described in the documentation here: https://docs.wildfly.org/34/High_Availability_Guide.html#injecting-a-cache-into-jakarta-ee-applications

Well, if I define cache container and local cache es described in documentation and inject org.infinispan.Cache as described in documentation, I get above mentioned exception WFLYEE0117. How to tell wildfly it should instantiate some implementation of org.infinispan.Cache interface? Am I missing something?
